# Customize Lookup form field (new, edit) with JSLink

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, jslink, edit-form, newform

How can I get the options for some *LookUp* field, in JSLink?

Code:

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    Templates: {
        Fields: {
            Initiative: {
                EditForm: CustomFieldInitiative,
                NewForm: CustomFieldInitiative
            }
        }
    }
});

function CustomFieldInitiative(ctx) {
    if (!ctx) return '';

    var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

    var fldName = "cbo_" + formCtx.fieldName;
    var fldValue = parseInt(formCtx.fieldValue);

    formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
        var cbo = document.getElementById(fldName);
        return cbo.options[cbo.selectedIndex].value;
    });

    var html = '<select id="' + fldName + '">'+
                // HOW I PUT THE OPTIONS OF LOOKUP FIELD INITIATIVE HERE?
                //<option value="{Lookup.Id}" data-parent="{Lookup.LookupPropertyPillar.Id}">{Lookup.Title}</option>
               '</select>';

    return html;
}
```

**How can I get the options (lookup values) from field?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point in your code where you want to get the choices,

```
ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Choices
```

is an array of lookup choice objects, which each have two properties, `LookupId` and `LookupValue`.

Here is a screenshot illustrating what I mean:

[image: choices array]

In order to find out what is available to you, I highly recommend setting a breakpoint in your script, and just clicking around to explore the `ctx` object, and see what you can find.

Comment: Yeah, i found this property too, but my problems is a little bit bigger. I need get another lookup field from choice.  Something like `<option value="choice.id" data-parent="choice.lookupfield.id">choice.title</option>`. I'm solving this with the REST API.

Comment: But the problem is I've to do REST request sync, and perform goes down.

Answer (score 1):

```
SPFieldLookup_Edit( ctx );
```

produces the default HTML for an SP Lookup field, you could take that HTML and work it.
If you want the individual options you have to dig into the Fieldschema (in your formCtx)

`SPFieldLookup_Edit` is from `clientforms.js`:

```
function SPFieldLookup_Edit(b) {
    if (b == null )
        return "";
    var a = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(b);
    if (a == null || a.fieldSchema == null )
        return "";
    if (a.fieldSchema.Throttled) {
        var d = String(a.fieldSchema.MaxQueryResult)
          , f = a.fieldSchema.Required ? STSHtmlEncode(StBuildParam(Strings.STS.L_LookupFieldRequiredLookupThrottleMessage, d)) : STSHtmlEncode(StBuildParam(Strings.STS.L_LookupFieldLookupThrottleMessage, d))
          , c = '<span style="vertical-align:middle">';
        c += f;
        c += "</span>";
        return c
    }
    if (a.fieldSchema.Required) {
        var e = new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidatorSet;
        e.RegisterValidator(new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.RequiredValidator);
        a.registerClientValidator(a.fieldName, e)
    }
    return a.fieldSchema.AllowMultipleValues ? SPFieldLookupMulti_Edit(b) : SPFieldLookup_DropDown_Edit(b)
}
```

#### All HTML producing Template functions:

```
'Text': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldText_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldText_Edit
},
'Number': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
},
'Integer': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
},
'Boolean': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_DefaultNoEncode,
    'EditForm': SPFieldBoolean_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldBoolean_Edit
},
'Note': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldNote_Display,
    'EditForm': SPFieldNote_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldNote_Edit
},
'Currency': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
},
'File': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldFile_Display,
    'EditForm': SPFieldFile_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldFile_Edit
},
'Calculated': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Empty,
    'NewForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Empty
},
'Choice': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldChoice_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldChoice_Edit
},
'MultiChoice': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldMultiChoice_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldMultiChoice_Edit
},
'Lookup': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldLookup_Display,
    'EditForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit
},
'LookupMulti': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldLookup_Display,
    'EditForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit
},
'Computed': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'EditForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
    'NewForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default
},
'URL': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldUrl_Display,
    'EditForm': SPFieldUrl_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldUrl_Edit
},
'User': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldUser_Display,
    'EditForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate,
    'NewForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate
},
'UserMulti': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldUserMulti_Display,
    'EditForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate,
    'NewForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate
},
'DateTime': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldDateTime_Display,
    'EditForm': SPFieldDateTime_Edit,
    'NewForm': SPFieldDateTime_Edit
},
'Attachments': {
    'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
    'DisplayForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default,
    'EditForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default,
    'NewForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default
}
```